# Spring boot upgrade causes tests to fail with hibernate exception "NULL not allowed for column REV"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-envers

For my Java Spring application, after upgrading Spring boot to version `2.7.0`, my tests started failing with this error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at com.core.SomeProject.Test.testSomething(SomeTest.java:224)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: 
NULL not allowed for column "REV"; SQL statement:
insert into revinfo (rev, revtstmp) values (null, ?) [23502-212]
```

After looking around, a commonly suggested solution was to modify the create statement for the `revinfo` table to make `rev` be auto-incremented like this:

```
<addAutoIncrement tableName="REVINFO" columnName="REV" columnDataType="INTEGER"/>
```

If this is actually the solution, how do I configure this in my Spring application?

It looks like the `revinfo` table is automatically generated; it's not explicitly defined in the Spring project. The classes that have an `@Audited` tag above them have an audited table automatically generated for them, so I don't know how I can make that column autoincrement. Any ideas would be appreciated, thanks!

This is on hibernate-core version `5.6.9.Final` and hibernate-envers version `5.3.20.Final`.

Comment: Are there any updates to this? I'm facing the same problems by updating from spring boot 2.7 to 3.1

Answer (score 0):

You can access the Database and alter the table to auto increment even on null values this works fine.

```
mysql> Create table employee(id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, Name Varchar(10));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.16 sec)
```

When a nul value is passed into this,

```
mysql> Insert into employee(id, Name) values(NULL, 'Sarathi');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.07 sec)
```

It wont consider the null and MySQL will return sequence number as seen below.

```
mysql> Select * from employee;
+----+---------+
| id | Name    |
+----+---------+
| 1  | Sarathi |
+----+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I'm getting this error when I run the test suite, which is configured to HSQL as the embedded database. So I'm not sure how to execute this SQL when the database is generated as part of Spring's test suite.